# How Avalanche Imagine Bundle can work on production environment?

Tags: symfony, bundle, liipimaginebundle

I try to use [AvalancheImagineBundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) and I don't understand how it can works in production environment.

The default cache_prefix is media/cache. All cached images will be in the myProject/web/media/cache directory and it's also a Symfony2 route :

```
Name                Method   Scheme Host Path
_imagine_thumbnail  GET      ANY    ANY  /uploads/cache/{filter}/{path}
```

If I do a test on this url "http://my-project.fr/app.php/", the bundle works fine:

1. The first time, I try to show the /app.php/media/cache/thumbnail/profile.jpg picture. The Symfony2 route is caught. The bundle return the cropped picture and cache it.
2. The second time, the route is caught again and the bundle redirects me to the cached picture /media/cache/

In short, the first time /app.php/media/cache -> bundle, and second time /media/cache -> assets

But in production environment, app.php is missing so how the bundle can do the difference ?

Comment: I think u should inspect your .htaccess

Comment: I use lighttpd but I think it's the same problem. "^/media/.+" => "$0", "^(/[^\?]*)(\?.*)?" => "/app.php$1$2". In my case, the first case never happens. The 'media' rules is cached before the 'app.php' rule. But if I delete the 'media' rules, I have an infinite redirection.

Comment: Haven't used Lighthttp, but the way it works in Apache is that that the request is passed to the front controller only if a file does not exist on a given path. [Here's](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.2/web/.htaccess#L37) the line that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` option does not exist in lighttpd so I switch to apache2 and everything work well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with lighttpd, so I can only point you to a direction where to look.

The "switch" is done via `.htaccess`, here are two relevant lines and explanation:

```
# If request is an existing file, then it's simply returned
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Else the request is pushed to the app.php front controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I think you're missing first part of this config.

P.S. Note that `app.php` isn't actually missing, it's just "hidden".